# Vue-cli with Promise-based HTTP clients: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'http'

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Could you help me identify this issue please.
I try to load remote data by clicking on the button but I have an error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'http'...

I have written couple tests with **tiny-json-http** and with **axios**.
My steps after creating a "vue-cli-error-http" project folder :

```
$ npm install -g vue-cli   

$ cd vue-cli-error-http   
$ vue init webpack .   
$ npm install axios --save
$ npm install tiny-json-http --save

$ npm run dev
```

I created a new component **LoaderTiny.vue** in *src/components/*:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{msg}} </h1>
    <hr />
    <button v-on:click="getData">Get Data</button>

  <ul v-if="posts && posts.length">
    <li v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="`p-${index}`">
      <p><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></p>
      <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul v-if="errors && errors.length">
    <li v-for="(error, index) in errors" :key="`error-${index}`">
      {{error.message}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</template>

<script>
import tiny from "tiny-json-http";
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: "LoaderTiny",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App",
      posts: [],
      errors: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function(event) {
      const reqURL = `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`;

      /*
      this.posts = [
        {
          userId: 1,
          id: 1,
          title:
            "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
          body:
            "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
        },
        {
          userId: 1,
          id: 2,
          title: "qui est esse",
          body:
        "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
        }
      ];
      */

      /*
      tiny.get( {reqURL} ).then(response => {
        // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
        console.log(response);
        this.posts = response.body.Items;
      }).catch(err =>  this.errors.push(err))
      */
      try {
        axios.get(reqURL)
          .then(response => {
            // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
            this.posts = response.data;
          })
          .catch(e =>  this.errors.push(e));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And in the Router (***src/router/index.js***):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import LoaderTiny from '@/components/LoaderTiny'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/test',
      component: LoaderTiny
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
  ]
})
```

Comment: I commented a line with import tiny from "tiny-json-http"; It looks like the error is inside tiny package

Comment: I am not familiar with `tiny-json-http` package. What does it do? Shouldn't `axios` be enough?

Comment: This is without CORS error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in Axios

Comment: By the way, when I replaced const reqURL = `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`; on the production https link I immediately received CORS error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ...

Comment: Then you will have to allow the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in `axios` headers.